# Apagar item de uma Array Dinamica

Tags: delphi

Bom, estou tentando usar esta Procedure para apagar items de array:

Antes declarei em Type:

```
TStringArray = array of string;
```

Em public:

```
filestoadd : TStringArray;
```

E no create:

```
for x:=0 to 5 do begin
SetLength(filestoadd, x);
filestoadd[x] := IntToStr(x)+'test';
end;
```

A procedure:

```
procedure DeleteElement(anArray:TStringArray;const aPosition:integer);
var
   lg, j : integer;
begin
   lg := length(anArray);
   if Length(anArray) < aPosition then
   exit;
   if aPosition = lg-1 then
     exit
   else if aPosition = lg-1 then begin //if is the last element
           //if TSomeType is a TObject descendant don't forget to free it
           //for example anArray[aPosition].free;
           Setlength(anArray, lg -1);
           exit;
        end;
   for j := aPosition to lg-2 do//we move all elements from aPosition+1 left...
     anArray[j] := anArray[j+1];//...with a position
   SetLength(anArray, lg-1);//now we have one element less
   //that's all...
end;
```

Estou tentando usar assim:

```
DeleteElement(filestoadd, ListBox1.ItemIndex)
```

Mas quando uso, dá acess violation 0040989C.
A linha de erro é exatamente a linha que chama a function:

> First chance exception at $004098C8. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x004098c8: read of address 0xfffffffc'. Process ExeGenerator.exe (5808)

Como posso ajeitar isso?

Answer (score 3):

Seu código tem alguns erros/inconsistências:

Você guarda o tamanho da variável `anArray` em `lg`, e em seguida chama novamente a função `length`.

O seu loop não esta movimentando a última posição do vetor, portanto você esta perdendo um dado que não deveria perder.

O seu `constructor` também possui problemas: ele realoca várias vezes o vetor, o que poderia ser feito apenas uma já que você sabe o tamanho dele com antecedência (6), além de não estar alocando memória com antecedência, o que acredito que seja a razão do `segmentation fault`.

Um último problema (alguém deve conferir se isto é realmente um problema, pois fazem vários anos que não programo mais Delphi, não me lembro de algumas particularidades), a variável `anArray` deve ser um parâmetro de entrada e saída, e portanto deve ser declarada como `var` na lista de parâmetros.

Sugiro o seguinte código:

```
constructor TMyClass.Create();
var
    size: integer;
begin
    size := 6;
    SetLength(filestoadd, size);
    for x := 0 to size - 1 do begin
        filestoadd[x] := IntToStr(x) + 'test';
    end;
end;

procedure DeleteElement(var anArray: TStringArray; const aPosition: integer);
var
   lg, j : integer;
begin
   lg := length(anArray);
   if lg <= aPosition then
       exit;
    for j := aPosition to lg - 2 do
        anArray[j] := anArray[j + 1];
    SetLength(anArray, lg - 1);
end;
```

Se puder colocar a linha do erro irá ajudar bastante, caso estas alterações não resolvam o problema.

**Análise da Mensagem de Erro**

> First chance exception at $004098C8. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x004098c8: read of address 0xfffffffc'. Process ExeGenerator.exe (5808)

A exceção ocorreu no momento que se tentou ler o endereço `0xFFFFFFFC`. Ou seja, ele estava tentando ler a última palavra de memória endereçável em uma máquina de 32 bits.

Geralmente, os endereços do programa são (muito simplificadamente) do seguinte modo: texto nos endereços baixos crescendo em direção aos endereços altos; stack nos endereços altos crescendo em direção aos endereços baixos; e a heap no meio de acordo com lógicas do Sistema Operacional.

O endereço `0xFFFFFFFC` é um endereço alto, e portanto ocupado pelas bases da stack. Não tenho conhecimento suficiente para dizer com certeza o que contém nestes endereços, mas acredito haver estruturas do SO utilizadas na inicialização do programa e que são protegidas.

Ou até (mais provável, acredito), no seu SO o texto fica nas regiões altas do programa, e são mapeados apenas com permissão de execução, causando o erro quando se tenta realizar a leitura.

Comment: Nada ainda. Ja editei o post.

Comment: Tente executar o programa no debugger, e inserir um breakpoint logo antes da procedure, executando instrução por instrução. No debugger vai ser possível verificar que todas as variáveis estão corretamente alocadas. É provável também que esteja ocorrendo alguma violação de memória em outro local e que ela só esteja aparecendo quando esta procedure é executada (undefined behavior).

Comment: Mostrou a mesma linha.

Comment: Testei aqui em um programa curto e não encontrei problemas. Acredito que o problema esteja em outro lugar do seu programa que esteja causando undefined behavior, e então nesta linha esta surgindo a segmentation fault. Sem mais informações, não tenho como ir além.

Comment: Estranho, porque tirando essa linha(que chama a função), não dá o erro.

Comment: É por isso que se chama `undefined behavior`. O comportamento é aleatório. É um dos piores problemas que há, pois a causa pode ser qualquer coisa. Só um grande conhecimento da documentação da linguagem, das bibliotecas sendo utilizadas e de boas práticas para evitar este tipo de erro. Se você colocar mais código na questão, com certeza poderei ajudar mais. Só gostaria de ressaltar que estou um pouco enferrujado em Delphi, mas essas teorias valem para a grande maioria das linguagens, inclusive Delphi.

Comment: Ah! Mais uma coisa que acabo de notar que comprova minha teoria. Vou alterar minha resposta.

Comment: Vou ver o que consigo fazer, se conseguir, posto aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Acabei não usando array, e sim TStringList.
http://www.activedelphi.com.br/forum/viewtopic.php?t=65822&sid=9d65d7309f79a1e91775e3525ea87322